How can I use VBA to create a macro in MS Word which will find text which contains a paragraph mark while ignoring any tracked revisions?
Background - In Word 2016, one can use the Find/Replace advance dialog to search for something like [sometext]^p[moretext] where the "^p" is the paragraph mark, and then replace it with just  ^p to remove the unwanted text. This all works as expected.
This stops working when one is working with Track Revisions turned on (in VBA: ActiveDocument.TrackRevisions = True). If ShowRevisionsAndComments is turned on, using Find/Replace will no longer work. It is as if the text being searched is: [sometext]<earlier deleted text>^p[moretext]<more earlier deleted text>. The presence of the <earlier deleted text> appears to throw off the Find/Replace.
The reason I say this is that if one turns off the ShowRevisionsAndComments so they are no longer visible on the screen, then the Find/Replace works as before.
Now my challenge is that I need to get the function of the Find/Replace within a VBA macro. And whether or not the tracked revisions are visible on the screen, Find/Replace will not find my [sometext]^p[moretext]. It would seem that the macro is always dealing with the entire text, including the <earlier deleted text> regardless of what may be visible on the screen.
I'm thinking that it may be impossible to do what I'm trying to do, but I thought I'd see if anyone here knows how to do this.
Word Document Text:
[sometext]<some earlier deleted text><carriage return>
[moretext]<more deleted text>
VBA Code:
Sub FindAndReplace() 
    Dim wrdFind As Find
    Dim wrdRange As Range
    Dim wrdDoc As Document
    Set wrdDoc = Application.ActiveDocument
    Set wrdRange = wrdDoc.Content
    Set wrdFind = wrdRange.Find

    With wrdFind
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Text = "[sometext]^p[moretext]"
        .Replacement.Text = " ^p"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    wrdFind.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End Sub


Have you tried ActiveDocument.Revisions.AcceptAll before executing the find method? Sidenote: assignment of wrdDoc is missing in your code.

Black cat - thanks for the suggestion! It looks like I can also do wrdRange.Revisions.AcceptAll which would only accept the revisions of the changes I have just made. I'll have to try them both out. Btw, thanks for pointing out the missing assignment. I had taken care of that earlier in the code, but missed it when cutting and pasting into stackoverflow.

Surely, Range also has the Revisions property. What is the essence, that even it is not seen on the screen the previous text is there if revision is turned on.

Essentially, if it is possible, I need to leave revisions on and not accepted, yet still be able to do the Find/Replace in the macro. Since one can do it in Word itself (if revisions are not visible), I am hoping that it can also be done in VBA.

Sorry, i can't reproduce, because in my version it doesn't work. If insertion and deletion visibility is off, the replace return: search item was not found.

Yes, that is exactly the problem. As long as Track Revisions was on when the text was deleted, the Find/Replace macro will return search item was not found. whether the revision visibility is on or off.

Cannot replace [sometext] with   (space) and [moretext] with `` (empty string) separately?
